# Split string into variables PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i'm trying to figure out the best way to spilt the following url string:

> area-FFFFFF_miles-100_profession-web+developer

basically into the following:

```
$area = "FFFFFF";
$miles = 100;
$profession = "web developer";
```

But i've got a brain block and can't really figure out the most efficient way to do it. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

-Edit- I could do with accounting for any missing values, such as:

> area-FFFFFF_miles-_profession-web+developer

missing the miles etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$params = explode('_', $input);
foreach($params as $param) {
    $kv = explode('-', $param);
    ${$kv[0]} = str_replace('+', ' ', $kv[1]);
}
```

This also account for missing values.

Comment: Seems to work spot on. Just what I needed. Thanks. There are a few answers that are virtually the same so thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use preg_split:

```
preg_split("/[_-]/",...);
```

Comment: That splits but it doesn't split in _variables_, still need to expand

Comment: Brilliant. Didn't think of that. Any way I could account for something like this: area-FFFFFF_miles-_profession-web+developer (For example, missing the miles value?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. miles isn't missing with your string

Comment: The value of miles is missing. Try looking at the 2 edits in the original post.

Comment: @Ben: ahhh ok now I got you, i didn't understood at a first glance

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$paramsStr = 'area-FFFFFF_miles-100_profession-web+developer';

$parts = explode('_', $paramsStr);
foreach($parts as $part) {
    $pair = explode('-', $part);
    ${$pair[0]} = $pair[1];
}
```

Comment: Damn, is this some kind of race? >_<

And @SiGanteng, you still have `${$kv[1]}`, where you need just $kv[1]