# php - how to get all variable values in separate variables

Tags: php

how to get all possible variable values in separate variables..... separated with commas

```
$bin="1,2,3,4,5,6,ABC,AAA,77,00,11,AS,Code";
```

**how to get all possible variables something like this.**

```
$NN01="1";
$NN02="2";
$NN03="3";
$NN04="4";
$NN05="5";
$NN06="6";
$NN07="ABC";
$NN07="AAA";
$NN08="77";
$NN09="00";
$NN10="11";
$NN11="AS";
$NN12="Code";
```

above sting can be separated with any operator other than comma thanks for your help....

Comment: What determines the name of the end variable? Should it simply be `$NNxx`? What if there are more than 100 variables... `$NNxxx`?

Comment: Creating such repetitive variables is silly. Use an array. [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: While you guys are probably right to question the application here, I don't think that it is impossible the OP has their reasons for wanting to do this. Suggest a better route, sure, but do so with the understanding that you are guessing the use case, and might be completely wrong in your assumption.

Comment: Checkout this other Question that should answer yours:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258665/split-string-into-variables-php

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to do that, but you can explode them to an array.

```
$bin="1,2,3,4,5,6,ABC,AAA,77,00,11,AS,Code";
// any delimiter in place of ','
$arr = explode(',',$bin);
echo $arr[0];
```

Edit: Okay, it's possible.  I wrongly stated that you won't be able to do that.

Comment: Downvoter want to explain themselves?

Comment: Well, you _could_ be able to do it using `eval()`... but your solution is of course much better. (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: +1 using an array is the way to go.

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler One _could_, but one _shouldn't_.

Comment: In all fairness, this answer doesn't address the question as asked, and it wrongly states that the OP "won't be able to do this", implying that it cannot be done. It can. Downvote-worthy, probably not, but this isn't an answer to the question as asked, strictly speaking.

Comment: I agree.  Saying it cannot be done is completely wrong.  I've posted a simple working answer.  However, I don't think that warrants a down vote.

Comment: @Hameed I disagree that one *shouldn't*.  What's the harm?

Comment: @Nilpo Perhaps I should have phrased it better. It is discouraged and there are only limited safe context that `eval` should be used if at all: [Eval is Evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)

Comment: @Hameed You are completely correct.  Sorry, somehow in all of that I managed to miss that we were talking about Eval.  I think it's time for sleep.

Answer (score 3):

```
$bin = "1,2,3,4,5,6,ABC,AAA,77,00,11,AS,Code";
list ($NN01,$NN02,$NN03,$NN04,$NN05,$NN06,$NN07,$NN07,$NN08,$NN09,$NN10,$NN11,$NN12) = $bin;
```

or for something completely dynamic

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($bin as $val) {
    $temp = 'NN' . str_pad(++$i, 2, '0');
    $$temp = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `explode` function to turn the initial value into an array:

```
$bin="1,2,3,4,5,6,ABC,AAA,77,00,11,AS,Code";
$array_of_values = explode(',' $bin);
```

That will give you a numerically indexed array, which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => ABC
    [7] => AAA
    [8] => 77
    [9] => 00
    [10] => 11
    [11] => AS
    [12] => Code
)
```

You can just use that and access individual values by their index:

```
echo $array_of_values[0]; // 1
```

See more about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

From there, if you want to set the values into variables, you can use this loop, which uses "variable variables":

```
$bin= "1,2,3,4,5,6,ABC,AAA,77,00,11,AS,Code";
$array_of_values = explode(',', $bin);
$vn = 'NN';
foreach ($array_of_values as $k=>$v) {
  ${$vn.$k} = $v;
}
echo 'NN1:'.$NN1; // NN1:2
echo 'NN2:'.$NN2; // NN2:3
echo 'NN2:'.$NN3; // NN3:4
```

Try it: http://codepad.org/Ee8F9F18

**Documentation**

- Arrays - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
- `explode` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
- Variable variables - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to use **extract**, and provide a desired prefix.

```
$bin="1,2,3,4,5,6,ABC,AAA,77,00,11,AS,Code";
```

This will give you $NN_0 .. $NN_11, where 'NN' is the prefix you chose.

```
extract( explode( ',', $bin ), EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'NN' );
```

Comment: Nice! I had thought about this route too, but forgot about the prefix argument and didn't want to loop the array to add keys. Well played :)  (OTOH, extract is very evil)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but why not to use [array()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) ?

It works simple.

```
$YourArray = array ( "NN01" => "1", "NN02" => "2") // And so on
```

Comment: He probably doesn't want to hardcode it...

Comment: Wasn't sure as the real question wasn't too clear. Seeing other answers make it a lot clearer now.